# My section of Columns Won't Center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get these columns to align centered with the other text above it but it's either all the way to the left or too far right.  I'm using HTML5, CSS3 and bootsrap v3.3.4.

```
<section id="international" class="international">
<div class="section-heading">
<h6 class="title-int wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".3s"> Available Internationally</h6>



<p class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".5s">
<div class="para-in">
         Appropriate controllers and power cords are available for your country
</div>
```

These are the columns that are either too far left or too far right - I'm trying to get it to align centered with the other text above it

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<p class="para-int">
  Power Formats
</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="col-s-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 "></div>
<div class="col-sm-1 ">

<p class="para-int">
    USA
</p>
<p class="para-int">
    110V
</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 ">

<p class="para-int">
    Europe
</p>
<p class="para-int">
    230V
</p>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-1 ">

<p class="para-int">
    Japan
</p>
<p class="para-int">
    100V
</p>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-1 ">

<p class="para-int">
    Australia
</p>
<p class="para-int">
    240V
</p>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-1 ">

<p class="para-int">
    UK
</p>
<p class="para-int">
    230V
</p>
</div>
<div class="col-s-2 "></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>  

</section>
```

Comment: Should your section-heading div have a closing tag?

Comment: it does have the closing tag...

Comment: I think I figured it out by doing this: <div class="col-sm-11"> <div class="col-s-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 "></div> –

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out by doing this:

```
<div class="col-sm-11"> 
<div class="col-s-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 ">
</div>
```